# Splash images in iOS universal applications: setting no splash for one version but not the other

Tags: iphone, ipad, splash-screen

I have the universal application both for iPhone and iPad. I need to have the splash screen for the iPhone application but no launch image for the iPad version.

If I remove the iPad's splash screen image then it loads the iPhone one. I tried to set iPad's launch image key to empty string in `application.plist` manually but it leads to an ugly random image.

When developing a universal application, can one have the splash screen for the iPhone version but no splash for the iPad? If yes - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to remove the splash screen? Only thing I can think of is to create a black image and use that as the splash screen to mimic the default black one.

Comment: Because splash screen has some default delay before starting an actual application. Say if your application has loaded in 0.1 second but the application have the splash screen, then your user will have to wait for N default delay seconds.

Comment: Well AFAIK, the 'splash screen' is just there to display while loading your application and providing a nice animation. There is no way to remove it, and I'm pretty sure the OS doesn't delay your app after the initial animation.

Answer (score -2):

You can create your splash screen and then can set the time to remove the splash screen or once the user tap on.

There are many [tutorials](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-splashscreen-display-in-the-iphone/) around to create splash screen programmatically. Just use that and set the timer to remove the splash screen.

But there is the tricky solution for that as well, just take the screen shot of your home page and use as splash image and set the timer, so when the user click on any component he/she would not feel that the splash image was loading actually.

Comment: I hope that may solve your problem. becuase even though if you set the black image it will take time to launch the app, so its better to create splash screen and set the timer.

Comment: That will still display the built in iOS animation when launching the app. It will just annoy your users by making them wait another pointless 4 seconds...